# Correct way of deploying to a subdirectory/subdomain an app that doesn't really support it

Tags: ssl, nginx, subdomain, web-deployment, subdirectory

I've been trying to deploy [kandan](https://github.com/kandanapp/kandan) to my home server, on a subdirectory, let's say it's `example.com`.

I have a few constraints I'd like to see met:

- must not be at website root (I'm hosting other stuff and apps)
- must be secured by SSL (already implemented on `example.com` but not for subdomains, which I would have to pay for)
- kandan does not support being hosted on subdirectories (you can't tell to it that it's hosted on `example.com/kandan` and have it automatically update its links)

I have listed my attempts [here](https://github.com/kandanapp/kandan/issues/378#issuecomment-52330553), but here's the gist of it:

- tweakings to nginx
- adding `--prefix=/kandan` to `thin start`
- `RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT="/kandan"`
- `map Kandan::Application.config.relative_url_root` before `run Rack::URLMap...` in `config.ru`
- tweaking the content of `run Rack::URLMap...` in `config.ru`
- `scope "/kandan"` in `routes.rb`
- `config.relative_url_root = "/kandan"` in `production.rb`
- many combinations of all the above

None of it did the job.

Currently I can show the main page with some missing elements (JS, API calls failing..) and some working elements (CSS is there..)

Is there a way to fully achieve what I want?